# Bootstrap columns are moving together

Tags: bootstrap-4

I have a container which contains two divs ( col-md-4 and col-md-8) and also I made a JQuery animation which gives the left div (col-md-4) a "-65%" amount of marginLeft when I click a toggle button. The problem is the other div (col-md-8) also moves with it to the left side as the first div moves. Is there a way to free the second div(col-md-8) from moving together with the first div (col-md-4) ?
Basically what I want to do is to hide and show the left div as I click the button, but want it to move over the second div rather than they move together in the row. Hope I could explain my request properly.
Thanks

Html code

```
<div id="row2" class="row justify-content-md-center">
                        <div id="listhide" class="col-md-4">
                            <div id="listhideinner" class="table table-striped">
                                <div id="output5"></div>
                                <div><button id="button">toggle</button></div>
                            </div>
                        </div>



                        <div id="figurerow" class="col-md-8">
                            <div id="pdfviewer" style="display:none" >
                                <h5 id="h5name" ></h5>
                                <iframe id="pdf" src="" style="width: 100%; height: 92%;" alt="pdf"></iframe>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
```

Animation

```
   var $div1 = $('#listhide')
$('#button').click(function() {
  $div1.toggleClass('isOut')
  var isOut = $div1.hasClass('isOut')
  $div1.animate({marginLeft: isOut ? '-35%' : '-65%'}, 300)
})
```

Comment: Please show some code.

Comment: added some code, thanks @F_Mekk

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved the problem, I should have used #listhideinner div instead of #listhide div, because it is the parent div, and we only want to child div to move so.

Animation (Updated one)

```
   var $div1 = $('#listhideinner')
$('#button').click(function() {
  $div1.toggleClass('isOut')
  var isOut = $div1.hasClass('isOut')
  $div1.animate({marginLeft: isOut ? '-35%' : '-65%'}, 300)
})
```